# main.storyboard option doesn't appear when I try to localize my App

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to translate my app to other languages; when I try to choose the targeted language main.storyboard option doesn't appear, why?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I solved by myself, select main.storyboard then file inspector then click on localize main.storyboard